# Sql Pivot on time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

> Table 1: Daily attendance data:

```
    att_date    emp_code    emp_name    in_time                out_time
    2018-10-21  9999         Test   2018-10-21 08:00:00.000   2018-10-22 06:00:00.000
```

> Table 2: Trnevents

```
emp_readr_id    DT              EVENTID
    9999    2018-10-24 07:00:00.000 0
    9999    2018-10-24 05:00:00.000 0
    9999    2018-10-24 03:00:00.000 0
    9999    2018-10-23 21:00:00.000 0
    9999    2018-10-23 19:00:00.000 0
    9999    2018-10-23 06:00:00.000 0
    9999    2018-10-22 06:00:00.000 0
    9999    2018-10-21 08:00:00.000 0
```

I used this query to get all times in between in time and out time ,below query works fine but i try to make in row by using pivot. While using pivot out time shows in next row.

```
declare @tempProcesstable as table(
    [id] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [time_stamp] datetime NULL,
    [AccessType] varchar(3)  NULL) 
insert into @tempProcesstable 

        select distinct t1.emp_Reader_id, t1.DT,t1.eventid from   daily_attendance_data t2 join trnevents t1
on t1.emp_reader_id=t2.emp_reader_id where   (CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), t2.att_Date, 23) >=CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), '2018-10-20', 23) 
                       and CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), t2.att_date, 23) <=CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), '2018-10-21', 23))
                   and
                   (t1.DT >=t2.in_time 
                       and  t1.DT <=t2.out_time)
                        --   and t1.emp_reader_id=1000
                               group by t1.emp_Reader_id,t1.dt,t1.eventid order by t1.emp_reader_id,DT asc
                  ; With CheckIns
As (Select Rowemp_reader_id = Row_Number() Over (Partition by id, Cast(time_stamp As Date) Order By time_stamp),
        id, time_stamp,
        [Date] = Cast(time_stamp As Date),

        [Time] = Cast(time_stamp As Time(0))
    From @tempProcesstable)
Select Pvt.id,B.emp_name ,  [Date], CHECK1, CHECK2,Cast(dateadd(ss,datediff(ss,CHECK1,CHECK2),0) As Time(0)) Total1,
 CHECK3, CHECK4,Cast(dateadd(ss,datediff(ss,CHECK3,CHECK4),0) As Time(0)) Total2
From (Select id, [Date], [Time],
        CHECKNum = 'CHECK' + Cast(Rowemp_reader_id As varchar(11))
    From CheckIns) As P
Pivot (Min([Time])
    For CheckNum In (Check1, [Check2], Check3, Check4)
    ) As Pvt    

     LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.employee AS B ON Pvt.id= B.emp_reader_id
```

My output:

```
id  emp_name    Date    CHECK1  CHECK2  Total1  CHECK3  CHECK4  Total2  
1048    Singh   2018-10-21  07:06:07    17:34:05    10:27:58    NULL    NULL    NULL    
9999    Test    2018-10-21  08:00:00    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
9999    Test    2018-10-22  06:00:00    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Expected output:

I want all times between in time and out time in night to morning also.
can any one help me to rectify this.

```
id  emp_name    Date    CHECK1  CHECK2  Total1  CHECK3  CHECK4  Total2  
1048    Singh   2018-10-21  07:06:07    17:34:05    10:27:58    NULL    NULL    NULL    
9999    Test    2018-10-21  08:00:00    06:00:00    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Your query too complex. could you provide some sample data and expect result from the sample to let your question simper :)

Comment: everthing works fine expected out if some employee have night shift e.g see my output 9999 has intime at 8:00 and outime at 06:00 for that case i want single row as above employee. Same date no pblm but next date it 's not proper

Comment: I wrote an answer you can try it, @Time Attendance System

Comment: thanks but not my expected output

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function make row number by each date.

then use condition aggregate function to do pivot

```
SELECT emp_readr_id,
       emp_name,
       [Date],
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN time END) CHECK1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN time END) CHECK2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN time END) CHECK3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN time END) CHECK4
FROM (
SELECT emp_readr_id,
       emp_name,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DT,120) 'Date',
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DT,120) ORDER BY DT) rn,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DT,108) time
FROM Daily d 
JOIN Trnevents t on t.DT between d.in_time and d.out_time
) t1
group by emp_readr_id,
       emp_name,
       [Date]
```

[sqlifddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=808828fc583c7fdca6be8993dae75fbc)

Comment: my expected output outtime nxt day means it will show next day time in same date only